# How can I use multiple apply with pandas

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, apply

I'm using pandas with Python to export Excel to JSON. It's my first day with this lib and with python :)

Excel file :
[My excel datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np87J.png)

or DataFrame :

```
     DATA1  NAME CLIENT  PHONE CLIENT  NAME BOSS  PHONE BOSS
0    123    JOHN         DOE           KING       KING
```

I'm trying to have a JSON like this :

```
[
  {
    "DATA1": 123,
    "CLIENT": [
      {
        "NAME CLIENT": "John",
        "PHONE CLIENT": "Doe"
      }
    ],
    "BOSS": [
      {
        "NAME BOSS": "King",
        "PHONE BOSS": "King"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I'm trying to get the first json array no problem, i'm using this :

```
df.groupby(["DATA1"], as_index=False)
  .apply(lambda x: x[['NAME CLIENT', 'PHONE CLIENT']].to_dict('r'))
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={0: 'CLIENT'})
   .to_json(path_or_buf='output_path.json', orient='records'))
```

But if I try to get both arrays at the same time it doesn't work... I try to execute multiple apply or agg function but it doesn't work and I don't know where I have to use the dict function :

```
 df.groupby(["DATA1"], as_index=False)
   .agg({'CLIENT' : lambda x: x[['NAME CLIENT', 'PHONE CLIENT']],
     'BOSS' : lambda x: x[['NAME BOSS', 'PHONE BOSS']]})
   .reset_index()
   .to_json(path_or_buf='output_path.json', orient='records'))
```

If someone can give me some help...
Thank you to all :)

Comment: Hi Lily, welcome to SO!  If you can post your input data as code instead of an image, it will be easier for people to answer.

Comment: Thank you ASGM, I updated this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate function to build each record as you want:

```
def f( df ):
    return { 'CLIENT': df[ ['NAME CLIENT', 'PHONE CLIENT'] ],
             'BOSS': df[ ['NAME BOSS', 'PHONE BOSS'] ], 
             'DATA1': df[ 'DATA1' ].values[0]
           }

df.groupby("DATA1", as_index=False).apply( f ).to_json(path_or_buf='output_path.json', orient='records')
```